# Interpreting repeated-measures oneway ANCOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, ancova, centering

I have a question on how to run a repeated-measures oneway ANCOVA. I have only one within-subjects factor (time) and I am interested in how a construct changes from T1 to T2. I would also like to add some time-invariant covariates (some are dummy-coded, some are continous).

I now read that some researchers recommend the following: 
- mean-center covariates
- interpret the covariates x within-subject interaction term
- rerun ANOVA without covariates and interpret main effect of within-subjects factor

When I run an ANOVA without the covariates, the main effect of the within-subjects factor (time) is highly significant. When I run the ANCOVA, all effects are not significant, except for the between-subjects effects of some covariates (but not highly). When I run the ANCOVA with mean-centered covariates, the within-subjects main effect remains highly significant, and has almost equal F-values as in simple ANOVA.

Which model should I interpret?